# How can I add a prefix to all filenames under a directory?

Tags: perl, file, batch-rename

I am trying to prefix a string (`reference_`) to the names of all the *.bmp files in all the directories as well sub-directories. The first time we run the silk script, it will create directories as well subdirectories, and under each subdirectory it will store each mobile application's sceenshot with `.bmp` extension.

When I run the automated silkscript for second time it will again create the *.bmp files in all the subdirectories. Before running the script for second time I want to prefix all the *.bmp with a string `reference_`.

For example `first_screen.bmp` to `reference_first_screen.bmp`,
I have the directory structure as below:

```
C:\Image_Repository\BG_Images\second
...
C:\Image_Repository\BG_Images\sixth
```

having `first_screen.bmp` and `first_screen.bmp` files etc...

Could any one help me out?

How can I prefix all the image file names with `reference_` string?

When I run the script for second time, the Perl script in silk will take both the images from the sub-directory and compare them both pixel by pixel.  I am trying with code below.
Could you please guide me how can I proceed to complete this task.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
&one;

&two;

sub one {

    use Cwd;

    my $dir ="C:\\Image_Repository";
    #print "$dir\n";
    opendir(DIR,"+<$dir") or "die $!\n";
    my @dir = readdir DIR;
    #$lines=@dir;
    delete $dir[-1];
    print "$lines\n";
    foreach my $item (@dir)
    {
        print "$item\n";
    }
    closedir DIR;
}

sub two {

    use Cwd;

    my $dir1 ="C:\\Image_Repository\\BG_Images";
    #print "$dir1\n";
    opendir(D,"+<$dir1") or "die $!\n";
    my @dire = readdir D;
    #$lines=@dire;
    delete $dire[-1];
    #print "$lines\n";
    foreach my $item (@dire)
    {
        #print "$item\n";
        $dir2="C:\\Image_Repository\\BG_Images\\$item";
        print $dir2;
        opendir(D1,"+<$dir2") or die " $!\n";
        my @files=readdir D1;
        #print "@files\n";  
        foreach $one (@files)
        {
            $one="reference_".$one;
            print "$one\n";
            #rename $one,Reference_.$one;
        }
    }
    closedir DIR;
}
```

I tried open call with '+<' mode but I am getting compilation error for the read and write mode.
When I am running this code, it shows the files in BG_images folder with prefixed string but actually it's not updating the files in the sub-directories.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking here.  Your text says one thing but your code shows something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't open a directory for writing. Just use [opendir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html) without the mode parts of the string:

```
opendir my($dir), $dirname or die "Could not open $dirname: $!";
```

However, you don't need that. You can use File::Find to make the list of files you need.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename;
use File::Find;
use File::Find::Closures qw(find_regular_files);
use File::Spec::Functions qw(catfile);


my( $wanted, $reporter ) = find_regular_files;
find( $wanted, $ARGV[0] );


my $prefix = 'recursive_';


foreach my $file ( $reporter->() )
    {
    my $basename = basename( $file );

    if( index( $basename, $prefix ) == 0 )
        {
        print STDERR "$file already has '$prefix'! Skipping.\n";
        next;
        }

    my $new_path = catfile( 
        dirname(  $file ), 
        "recursive_$basename"
        );

    unless( rename $file, $new_path )
        {
        print STDERR "Could not rename $file: $!\n";
        next;
        }

    print $file, "\n";  
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should probably check out the [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) module for this - it will make recursing up and down the directory tree simpler.

You should probably be scanning the file names and modifying those that don't start with `reference_` so that they do.  That may require splitting the file name up into a directory name and a file name and then prefixing the file name part with `reference_`.  That's done with the [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) module.

At some point, you need to decide what happens when you run the script the third time.  Do  the files that already start with `reference_` get overwritten, or do the unprefixed files get overwritten, or what?

The reason the files are not being renamed is that the rename operation is commented out.  Remember to add `use strict;` at the top of your script (as well as the `-w` option which you did use).

If you get a list of files in an array `@files` (and the names are base names, so you don't have to fiddle with File::Basename), then the loop might look like:

```
   foreach my $one (@files)
   {
        my $new = "reference_$one";
        print "$one --> $new\n";
        rename $one, $new or die "failed to rename $one to $new ($!)";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

With the aid of `find` utility from [coreutils for Windows](http://getgnuwin32.sourceforge.net/):

```
$ find -iname "*.bmp" | perl -wlne"chomp; ($prefix, $basename) = split(m~\/([^/]+)$~, $_); rename($_, join(q(/), ($prefix, q(reference_).$basename))) or warn qq(failed to rename '$_': $!)"
```

Comment: Why not: find -iname '*.bmp' -exec mv '{}' reference_'{}' \; #?  I don't know Perl so I have no clue what the second end of the pipe's doing (and I couldn't really understand the OP's question, either...).

Comment: @strager: Consider the difference: dirname/img.bmp -> dirname/reference_img.bmp and dirname/img.bmp -> reference_dirname/img.bmp